# Dax -- Dividing by aggregates from two different facts

Tags: powerbi, sql-server-2016, dax, ssas-tabular

I am trying to convert a piece of SQL to dax.

It only involves two tables, both facts and a common dimension attribute, Encounter.
I want to sum all charges by encounter and sum collections by encounter, filtered to only collections of TransactionRollup_Name = Contractual, TransactionTypeDescription = Adjustment, posted last month.

I will filter the System and Action <> Delete in the reporting client (powerbi or excel)

Once these are obtained I want the sum of contractual collections where the portion of contractual collections over total encounter charges is >= .9 and < 1

SQL:

> ```
> DECLARE @startdate INT = 20181201
> ,     @thrudate INT = 20181231
> ,     @systemcode VARCHAR(1) = '1';
>
>
> SELECT    SUM(coll.Contractual)
> FROM  (   SELECT      SUM(Amount) * -1 Contractual
>           ,           col.EncounterID
>           FROM
>                       dwo.FactCollections        col
>           JOIN        dwo.DimTransactionCode_mds mds ON             col.mds_TransactionID = mds.SK_TransactionKey
>           WHERE
>                       mds.TransactionRollup_Name = 'Contractual'
>                       AND mds.TransactionTypeDescription = 'Adjustment'
>                       AND col.SystemID = TRY_CONVERT(INT, @systemcode)
>                       AND col.Action <> 'Delete'
>                       AND col.PostDateTime >= @startdate
>                       AND col.PostDateTime <= @thrudate
>           GROUP BY    col.EncounterID ) coll
> JOIN  (   SELECT      EncounterID
>           ,           SUM(Amount) Charge
>           FROM        dwo.FactCharges ldg
>           WHERE
>                       ldg.SystemID = TRY_CONVERT(INT, @systemcode)
>                       AND ldg.Action <> 'Delete'
>           GROUP BY    ldg.EncounterID )  chg ON chg.EncounterID = coll.EncounterID
> WHERE
>       chg.Charge <> 0
>       AND chg.Charge IS NOT NULL
>       AND coll.Contractual / chg.Charge >= .90
>       AND coll.Contractual / chg.Charge < 1.0;
> ```

Attempted Dax Measure:

```
90%-99.99% of Charges :=
CALCULATE (
    'MeasureTable'[Sum of Contractual Adjustments],
    FILTER (
        'FactCollections',
        DIVIDE (
            'MeasureTable'[Sum of Contractual Adjustments],
            'MeasureTable'[ChargeTotal]
        )
            >= .90
            && DIVIDE (
                'MeasureTable'[Sum of Contractual Adjustments],
                'MeasureTable'[ChargeTotal]
            )
                < 1.0
    )
)

Charge := SUM ( 'FactCharges'[Amount] )

Sum of Contractual Adjustments :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( FactCollections[Amount] ) * ( -1 ),
    FILTER (
        'Transaction Code',
        'Transaction Code'[TransactionTypeDescription] = "Adjustment"
            && 'Transaction Code'[TransactionRollup_Name] = "Contractual"
    )
)
```

Sample data on one encounter, per request.

[image: sample data]

**Addendum**
Going a different route with the dax, this gets me 1/2 way.
The summarizecolumns query gets me a result set that aggregates both charges and contractual collections up to the encounter and calculates the ratio of contractuals / charges.

The end result would need to filter this intermediate result set where

- contractual / charge ratio is >= .9 and < 1
- post dates for contractual collections should be filtered by reporting client filter context
- All post dates for charges should be included, regardless of the post date filter context in the reporting client

I have no idea how to do that second part in dax though.

```
> EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
>     'Encounter'[Encounter],
>     "ChargeAmount", SUMX ( 'FactCharges', 'FactCharges'[Sum Charge Amount] ),
>     "ContractualAmount", SUMX (
>         'FactCollections',
>         CALCULATE (
>             'FactCollections'[Sum of Adjustments],
>             'Transaction Code'[TransactionRollup_Name] = "Contractual"
>         )
>     ),
>     "Contractual : Charge", DIVIDE (
>         SUMX (
>             'FactCollections',
>             CALCULATE (
>                 'FactCollections'[Sum of Adjustments] * -1,
>                 'Transaction Code'[TransactionRollup_Name] = "Contractual"
>             )
>         ),
>         SUMX ( 'FactCharges', 'FactCharges'[Sum Charge Amount] )
>     ) )
```

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you have some sample data and desired output to work with.

Comment: Added sample of one account to original post.